# Query a 3-way relationship in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to figure out how to query this relationship without using find_by_sql

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items
  belongs_to :user
end

class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items
end
```

this should be what we are using but How would I do this not by find_by_sql
in user.rb

```
def self.find_users_who_like_by_item_id item_id
  find_by_sql(["select u.* from users u, lists l, list_items li where l.list_type_id=10 and li.item_id=? and l.user_id=u.id and li.list_id=l.id", item_id])
end
```

I've tried several different includes / joins / merge scenarios but am not able to get at what I'm trying to do.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to tell exactly what query you're trying to do here, but it looks like you want the user records where the user has a list with a particular list_type_id and containing a particular item. That would look approximately like this:

```
User.joins(:lists => [:list_items]).where('lists.list_type_id = ? and list_items.item_id = ?', list_type_id, item_id)
```

This causes ActiveRecord to execute a query like the following:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "lists" ON "lists"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "list_items" ON "list_items"."list_id" = "lists"."id" WHERE (lists.list_type_id = 10 and list_items.item_id = 6)
```

and return the resulting collection of User objects.

Comment: @timpone Yes. Rails will let you reference a table in a `.where` that you attached using `.includes` instead of `.joins`. That said, I don't really approve of that practice. For clarity, I use `.joins` when joining for query purposes (as here), and `.includes` specifically for eager loading, which is what it's intended for. You can chain both of them, e.g `User.includes(:lists).joins(:lists => [:list_items]).where(<stuff>)`